# java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed when running Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets

So i get the above error in my tomcat server. The web app runs fine but i get this error and it leads me to the while loop in one of my classes in java. I have looked at other answers similar but cannot figure out what i do wrong. I tried multiple solutions that make sense to me but still the same thing.

Here is where the error points to:

```java
while (rs.next()) {
```

full code:

```java
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String email = request.getParameter("uname");
        String password = request.getParameter("psw");
        boolean val = false;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("removed this path to file");
            Statement select = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (email.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(1)) && password.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(2))) {
                    connection.close();
                    val = true;

                }
                rs.close();
            }
            if(!val)
            connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(val) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/calculate.jsp");
        }else {
            request.setAttribute("name", "Wrong username or password!");
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
        }

        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: pls send help!!

Comment: You close the `ResultSet` in the loop. Move it out of the loop and it will be working correctly!

Comment: @csabinho its te same when outside the loop

Comment: You're closing connection (if email and password match) before resultset has been closed. I advise use finally block to close `rs` and `connection`.

Comment: @zforgo pefect! that worked thanks!